# Reasons why web service use hashes as ID?

Tags: web-services, url

So I see that a yelp url looks like this

http://www.yelp.com/biz_attribute?biz_id=doldrYLTdR9aYckHIsv55Q

The biz_id is a hash-like string, instead of the more commonly seen integer or mongoID. Aside from obfuscation, is there other reasons why one would use a hash as a ID instead of the ID in the database?

Comment: API handshaking protocol can be one, i.e. oauth 2, but hashing is mainly exactly what you describe

Comment: MongoIDs are pretty hashy looking.

Answer (score 0):

One can imagine several reasons, but a good reason that relates to MongoDB is to use a hash as an ID is for a shard key. A good shard key is one that distributes writes across separate shards, thereby achieving good write scaling. A hash is a good way to ensure writes are well distrubuted to separate shards.